# Number of Cosets of Intersection of Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Similar question has been asked on SE before but the problem statement is usually more specific and gives more information (in particular, tells you what to prove), but this problem asks to prove or disprove: For a group $G$ and subgroups $H$ and $K$, if $|G:H|$ and $|G:K|$ are finite then so is $|G:H \cap K|$.

Is there an easy way to see this is true with given just statement?

Comment: $H\cup K$? What about the title? (Did they change the formatting on the \cup ? It looks more squarish.)

Comment: You beat me to my edit by about 12 seconds. I did cup instead of cap on accident.

Comment: Here's a hint: Any coset of $H\cap K$ is the intersection of a coset of $H$ and a coset of $K$.

Comment: Note that $[H:H\cap K] \leq [G:K]$ and $[G:H\cap K]=[G:H][H:H\cap K]$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I got it. As Meelo stated, we have $g(H \cap K)=gH \cap gK$. To see this if $x \in g(H \cap K)$ then $x=gs$ for some $s \in H \cap K$. But then $x=gs \in gH$ and $x=gs \in gK$ so $x \in gH \in gK$ so $g(H \cap K) \subseteq gH \cap gK$. Similarly if $x \in gH \cap gK$ then $x=gs$ for $s \in H$ and $x=gt$ for $t \in H$. But then $s=t$ so $x \in g(H \cap K$ so $g(H \cap K) \supseteq gH \cap gK$. Hence any coset of $H \cap K$ is is the intersection of a coset of $H$ and and $K$ so we have $|G:H \cap K| \leq |G:H||G:K|$ which is finite by assumption.